# Overflow Issue with VirtualQueryEx in C# compiled for x64

Tags: c#, .net, memory, openprocess

I've been trying to create my own memory reader in C# based on a couple of articles I've seen on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/716227/Csharp-How-to-Scan-a-Process-Memory). I got everything working as I would have liked when compiled for 32-bit Windows, but the issues began when I tried to convert over to a 64-bit build.

I was able to get [`VirtualQueryEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx) to work in a 64-bit C++ test project, where the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` is already defined, and the `BaseAddress` member is a `PVOID`.

When I tried to move over to C#, I have to define `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` myself as indicated in the CodeProject example above that I am using as guidance.

The below code works for applications that have small memory profiles, but for larger applications, the `MI.BaseAddress` variable below seems to truncate to 2,147,356,672, and the program is stuck in an infinite loop, where `currentAddress` is always equal to `MI.BaseAddress + MI.RegionSize` (before casting to `ulong`).

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

```
public struct MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION
{
    public ulong BaseAddress;
    public ulong AllocationBase;
    public int AllocationProtect;
    public ulong RegionSize;
    public int State;
    public ulong Protect;
    public ulong Type;
}
```

-

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern int VirtualQueryEx(IntPtr hProcess, IntPtr lpAddress, out MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION lpBuffer, uint dwLength);
```

-

```
public void getBlocks(int pid)
{
    totalBytes = 0;
    if (addresses != null)
        addresses = null;
    addresses = new List<UIntPtr>();
    if (sizes != null)
        sizes = null;
    sizes = new List<UInt64>();
    setPID(pid);
    getHandle();

    ulong currentAddress;
    ulong maxAddress;

    SYSTEM_INFO SI;
    GetSystemInfo(out SI);
    maxAddress = (ulong)SI.maximumApplicationAddress;
    currentAddress = (ulong)SI.minimumApplicationAddress;

    MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION MI;

    while (currentAddress < maxAddress)
    {
        VirtualQueryEx(hProc, (IntPtr)currentAddress, out MI, (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION)));
        if (MI.State == MEM_COMMIT)
        {
            totalBytes += (ulong)MI.RegionSize;
        }
        currentAddress = (ulong)MI.BaseAddress + (ulong)MI.RegionSize;
    }
```

Comment: Your MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION does not look good. http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/Structures/MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.html

Comment: Protect and Type are *int*, not *ulong*.  Do favor using *IntPtr* for the fields that you now declared *ulong*, that way your code will work in both 32-bit and 64-bit mode.

Comment: @usr: Thank you, from that page I was able to find sample code that fixed my problem.

[link]http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32/VirtualQueryEx.html